# Default datetime picker in visual studio 2015 showing only date picker not allowing to select time

Tags: datetime, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2015

I am using visual studiio 2015 and i am using its default datetime picker in my MVC5's App. i am facing problem while showing the datetime picker. it is showing only date picker and not time picker. but i need time picker also. here is my code of datetimepicker in model

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = false)]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Start DateTime is required")]
public Nullable<System.DateTime> start_date_time { get; set; }
```

while i set `DateTime` in place of `Date` No Controller comes only textbox appear.

Comment: Have you tried http://forums.asp.net/t/1975676.aspx?Tutorial+for+Adding+Datepicker+in+MVC+5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no *default datetime picker in MVC5*. What the `[DataType]` attribute does is render the `type` attribute for the `<input>` element your generating that will then be used by the browser to render the appropriate HTML5 control if supported. In the case of `DataType.Date`, it generates `<input type="date" ... />`

At the current time only recent versions of Chrome support `type="date"`. If you tested this using IE or FireFox, you would only get a standard textbox.

Using `[DataType(DataType.DateTime)]` generates `type="datetime"` but this is not currently supported in either Chrome, IE or FireFox, which is why you see only the standard textbox.

Recent versions of Chrome however do support `type="datetime-local"` which will render a control allowing you to select both a date and a time. There is no `[DataType]` type which generates this but you can use

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.start_date_time, "{0:s}", new { @type = "datetime-local" })
```

Note `"{0:s"}` is shorthand for `"{0:yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss}"`

You can compare various versions of browsers and which of the HTML5 field types they support using [this site](https://html5test.com/compare/browser/chrome-44/firefox-40/ie-11.html).

Due to the current limited support, I recommend you consider using a jquery datetimepicker plugin rather than browsers HTML implementations.

Comment: In this another problem occures that it does not show in firefox

Comment: Use bootstrap's controll

Comment: @BeyondTheworld, Which bit about _this is **not currently supported in ..... FireFox**,_ do you not understand?

Comment: Yeah i got that but what should i do now .... should i move on bootstrap's controll ??

Comment: There are numerous datetimepicker controls you can consider - a few of them listed [here](http://www.jqueryrain.com/demo/jquery-date-time-picker/)